# Button alignment improper in Table Layout after adding "fourth" button

Tags: android, android-layout

Something wrong with my TableLayout. I am not able to display all four buttons properly. Also i want the circle badge to be shown properly above text and not on text.

How to correct this. Thanks in advance!!

Button Layout :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#4982AE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Button One"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Button Two"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Button Three"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/survey"
                        android:background="#092435"
                        android:text="Button Four"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                        android:layout_width="65dip"
                        android:layout_height="65dip" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textOne"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/survey"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/survey"
                        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

badge_circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <corners
    android:radius="10dip"/>
  <solid
    android:color="#F00"/>
  <stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FFF"/>
  <padding
    android:left="5dip"
    android:right="5dip"
    android:top="5dip"
    android:bottom="5dip"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Why are you using TableLayout?? This thing is much simpler with linear layout.

Comment: can you use linear layout or need to must use table layout because its become easy and manage to good work in linear layout rather than table layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_weight="1"` to RelativeLayout for fourth button.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#4982AE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Button One"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Button Two"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#092435"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="Button Three"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                    android:background="#85929B" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/survey"
                        android:background="#092435"
                        android:text="Button Four"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                        android:layout_width="65dip"
                        android:layout_height="65dip" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textOne"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/survey"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@id/survey"
                        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```